# Relationship between nilpotency index and rank of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Assume two n-dimensional nilpotent matrices **A** and **B** with respective ranks $r_{A}$ and $r_{B}$ such that $r_{A}>r_{B}$. Can we conclude that the nilpotency index of **A** is always greater than **B**?

Comment: The index of a matrix is equal to the rank, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728825/nilpotent-operator-of-index-n.  So if $r_A>r_B$ then then nilpotency index of $A$ is greater then $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect. Here is an example
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}\right),\
B=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc|cc|cc}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}\right).
$$
We have $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$, $\operatorname{rank}(B)=3$ and $B^2=0$, $A^2\neq0$, $A^3=0$.